# Code execution time profiler for Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, performance, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm working with multi-layered application using .Net Core. My application is faster initially and getting slower after sometime. I was trying to debug the code to understand which line is making it slower, but not successful. Can anyone suggest me how to profile to know the execution time of the each line. Thanks.

Comment: Related: [How to profile and measure C#/C++/Java code performance with VSCode?](/q/69166499/11107541)